# Can I log in with other user's account?

Tags: bash, login, command-line

I would like to ask you about login command in bash shell Ubuntu.

I entered #login then it asks me about username and password. Is this a way to log in with other user's account?

Answer (score 23):

`login` does exactly what the name says, it logs a user in and sets up the environment, but the login command is not intended for switching to another user account on the command line. For this you would either use `su username` to switch to another account, or `sudo -u username` to run just a single command as another user.